# Apple IIGS: Is there a way to boot and run an Apple II OS in E0/E1 in native CPU mode?

Tags: apple-iigs

Apple //GS: Is there a way to boot and run an Apple ][ OS in E0/E1 in native CPU mode? No GS features are required. 1MHz clock like on previous Apple2s is perfect. The reason for needing this is because there are hardware features present in E0/E1 Mega II space which are unavailable to the emulation pages 0/1 when we try to use peripheral cards designed for old Apple2s.